# If I have a component that should render on the client side, does that mean all of their children also don't render on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

So in Next 13 I need to mark a component that shouldn't be a server component with `use client`. Context providers get flagged as so, and I am forced/asked to mark them with the `use client` otherwise I get an error.

But my entire app is wrapped with this providers, mainly for authentication purposes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Tsabary! Check the linked thread's answer. Let me know if it doesn't answer your question. We will reopen it :)